# Split Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using yfinance to get option chain information. In the yfinance documentation it says data when retrieved would be pandas dataframe.

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

#retrieving for specific date
data = tk.option_chain('2021-03-26')
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

Then I try this to split the text

```html
data['ExpirationDate'] = data['contractSumbol'].str.slice(start=4, stop=10)
```

Output:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

so I try to define column by integer like this:

data['ExpirationDate'] = data[0].str.slice(start=4, stop=10)

Output error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

I try:
data['ExpirationDate'] = data[0].slice(start=4, stop=10)

but get this error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'slice'

End goal is to have a dataframe with just the expiration dates formatted as dates:

[image]

Comment: `data` is not a dataframe.  It is of type:  `yfinance.ticker.Options`

Comment: what you want to get exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that option_chain() return an object of type `yfinance.ticker.Options` which contains a collections of pandas Dataframes

```
type(data)
```

> yfinance.ticker.Options

```
type(data[0])
```

> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

```
data[0]

contractSymbol  lastTradeDate   strike  lastPrice   bid ask change  percentChange   volume  openInterest    impliedVolatility   inTheMoney  contractSize    currency
0   MSFT210326C00140000 2021-03-15 04:09:20 140.0   93.03   91.50   92.15   0.000000    0.000000    NaN 0   1.819337    True    REGULAR USD
1   MSFT210326C00145000 2021-03-16 19:35:26 145.0   93.87   86.40   87.20   0.000000    0.000000    2.0 0   1.695314    True    REGULAR USD
2   MSFT210326C00170000 2021-02-09 14:40:03 170.0   72.75   67.80   68.65   0.000000    0.000000    NaN 0   2.339848    True    REGULAR USD
3   MSFT210326C00175000 2021-03-01 20:24:42 175.0   57.80   56.45   57.10   0.000000    0.000000    40.0    28  1.082524    True    REGULAR USD
4   MSFT210326C00180000 2021-02-18 16:22:29 180.0   51.00   51.40   52.35   -6.450001   -11.227155  1.0 4   1.024419    True    REGULAR USD
5   MSFT210326C00190000 2021-03-04 16:58:48 190.0   49.65   41.50   42.25   0.000000    0.000000    1.0 59  0.839845    True    REGULAR USD
6   MSFT210326C00195000 2021-03-18 13:41:08 195.0   38.75   36.65   37.30   0.000000    0.000000    1.0 0   0.774416    True    REGULAR USD
```

To extract  date of expiration

```
df = data[0]
df["contractSymbol"].str[4:10]
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.

Added this to choose the first dataframe to process

I'm selecting the first column of the dataframe by [0]
1 of 2
Tried two ways the next step:

df['ExpirationDate'] = df[0].str.slice(start=4, stop=10)

Error

https://miamisublimation.tinytake.com/tt/NTIxNTI1N18xNjMxMTg1Mw


2 of 2

mid = df[0].str[3:8]

Error

https://miamisublimation.tinytake.com/tt/NTIxNTI1NF8xNjMxMTg1MA

Any guess what the errors mean? I can't find any specific error to google and troubleshoot.

Comment: you wanna extract contractSymbol starting from 5th characater until 10?

Comment: correct. That is the date of expiration of the option.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you @Yefet!

Comment: Final working code in case anyone needs it in the future. https://miamisublimation.tinytake.com/tt/NTIxNTI4NV8xNjMxMjAwMg